# Angular 4 Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, routes

I using `ng serve` and have such routing config

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AuthComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'registration',
            component: RegistrationComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'restore',
        component: RestoreComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'newpass',
        component: NewPassComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

and two button in auth.component.html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active-link">Login</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/registration" routerLinkActive="active-link">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

when I click on login link, angular navigate me to login page without errors, but when I reload [localhost:4200/login](http://localhost:4200/login) page, I got this error

[Console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHwAw.png)

but page loaded successful and components will work.

So, how I can fix it and why angular make second NavigationStart to /login/(login) ?

Comment: you can try to use `HashLocationStrategy`

Comment: @n00dl3 but when I refresh /reload page, angular doesnt give error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I solved this problem. In AuthComponent I have this code

```
let isAuthorized = await this.checkAuthorization();
if (isAuthorized) {
  this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], {relativeTo: this.route});
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['login'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

so I make redirect from /login to /login/login but route config doesnt have this path

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use children of path "". Try to use this:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pathToAuth', // change to your path
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'registration',
        component: RegistrationComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'restore',
    component: RestoreComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'newpass',
    component: NewPassComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: if pathToAuth === "" try to use without children elements: export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'registration',
    component: RegistrationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'restore',
    component: RestoreComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'newpass',
    component: NewPassComponent
  }
];  Sorry for format

Comment: but LoginComponent and RegistrationComponent is a forms, and AuthComponent is a general layout which contain one of form. So when I open /login page, LoginComponent have to launch inside AuthComponent

Comment: do you use <router-outlet></router-outlet> to show child component? Please show me the full structure of your template. Maybe you forgot square brackets for routerLink and routerLinkActive attribute?

Comment: auth.component.html
`<aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="logo" src="../../../assets/images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active-link">Login</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/registration" routerLinkActive="active-link">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</aside>
<figure>
...
</figure>`

but error appear when I refresh login page, not after click on login link